# Batch: How to use "devcon status" return as IF condition?

Tags: batch-file, devcon

I am having trouble with my digitizer and pen. The palmrejection detects the pen only when it's like 1cm above the screen.

So I'm trying to make a batch which disables or enables the touchscreen when executed.

```
devcon disable "@HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000"

devcon enable "@HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000"
```

Currently i have 2 seperate batches with one of the above commands and they work fine.
But I want it in 1 file with an `IF ELSE` clause.

```
D:
cd D:\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64
SET /P Test=devcon status "@HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000"
IF %Test% EQU 1(
devcon disable "@HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000"
)ELSE(
devcon enable "@HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000"
)
```

I tried, but I don't know how to use the status return as IF condition to en- or disable the touchscreen.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>D:

D:\>cd D:\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64

D:\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64>SET /P Test=devcon status "@HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000"

>>devcon status "@HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000"
```

This is returned by cmd when executed. The last line isn't executed, I can still edit it and press enter, then cmd closes.

```
D:\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64>devcon status "@HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000"
HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000
    Name: HID-konformer Touchscreen
    Device is disabled.
1 matching device(s) found.
```

status if device is disabled

```
D:\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64>devcon status "@HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000"
HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000
    Name: HID-konformer Touchscreen
    Driver is running.
1 matching device(s) found.
```

status if device is enabled

Comment: I don't know `devcon`. What's the exact output of `devcon status "@HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000"` (in both cases)?

Comment: Have you considered to type `if /?` into a Command Prompt window and to cross-check your syntax?

Comment: I added the status outputs to my question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the output of a command into a variable, use a `for /f` loop. Filter the line you need (`Device is xxxxx`) and get the third token (word) from this line:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('devcon status "@HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000"^|find "Device is"') do set "status=%%a"
echo status is %status%
```

The rest of your code is not quite correct (`batch` is a bit picky with spaces) and I changed the `if` to string comparison to make it safe against an empty `%status%` variable:

```
IF "%status%" == "running" (
  devcon disable "@HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000"
) ELSE (
  devcon enable "@HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000"
)
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

I tested it, but it always disables the screen :D The output of cmd during this script is

`D:\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64>set "status=HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000"

D:\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64>set "status=Name:"

D:\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64>set "status=Driver"

D:\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64>set "status=1"
status is 1`

It always gets status 1, no matter if enabled or disabled.
I try to figure out how to take another part of the status return to use for comparison.

Comment: the `1` you get is the first token of the last line ("**1** matching device(s) found."). I changed the code according to the provided output of `devcon`. I don't use `devcon`, so I hope it works.

Comment: Thanks! It fristly didn't work correct, but I saw that the output is "Driver is..." or "Device is...", so I just changed the IF clause to `IF "%status%" == ""`. I could also have switched the operations and changed the IF clause to `IF "%status%" == "disabled"`, but it works now like it should :-)

Comment: oh - I didn't notice the output is different ("driver" vs. "device"). Which reminds me of a simpler solution: `devcon status "@HID\ELAN0732&COL01\5&242C8B19&1&0000" |find "running" >nul && set "status=running" || set "status=disabled"`